# Hyper-V Vagrant - Running out of memory but not sure why

Tags: linux, hyper-v, vagrant

[image: Output from Hyper-V terminal]

I understand that something is using the memory, and forcing OOM killer to kick in and start killing processes, to the point where there is nothing more to kill and a kernel panic happens.

However, I've tried tweaking server settings, increasing RAM, adjusting the swap and a few other things along the way, but this issue keeps happening.

The same box on a different PC works perfectly, and will stay up for days an days. But on this particular machine, it keeps throwing these errors.

The host machines that I have tried this on both have 8gb of RAM, and I usually start the VM with 1gb, allowing it to use 2gb if required.

Any advice would be welcome,

Comment: Well, it's clear what the problem is. The phrase "out of memory" appears more than a couple of times there.

Comment: Cheers @EEAA - I've been having this issue for a few months and looked at various memory issues (as previously stated). Just trying to reach out for any more information at the moment.

Something is killing the memory, clearly, but I'm not sure where to start in terms of debugging this.

Comment: Well, set up some type of monitoring to collect per-process memory usage. After you do that, the culprit should be fairly easy to spot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @EEAA, I looked into per-process memory usage (taking some ideas from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92493/sorting-down-processes-by-memory-usage)

By using: `ps aux --sort -rss`

This highlighted that SQL was using far too much memory, so I looked at changing my.cnf with some lower numbers and this help considerably.

http://mysqltuner.com/ helped a lot